# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Today, I thought to have found an answer to a question asked by myself.
([IPv6 subnets without delegated prefix](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79055/ipv6-subnets-without-delegated-prefix/79434#79434))
Unfortunately, it was deleted by a moderator and no one can see that answer (nor can they see that this is the *correct* answer - at least in my opinion).
I really would like to know why that answer was deleted, but unfortunately, there's no hint on how to improve it.
I already made a small change (and removed the first words which were just a polite "Thank you", although it was not a "Thank you" post, but the full answer.
But I even don't know if that was the reason.

I would be glad if anyone could explain that to me, as i always liked the communities here...
But in none of them a post from me was ever deleted.

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you posted as an answer looked very much like a comment and was converted to such. After editing it was more of an answer and was restored.